# Debugging gradle in Docker Compose

Tags: docker, gradle, docker-compose

I'm trying to debug a gradle application running in docker, but when I try to connect the debugger on port 5005 I am getting the following error:

```
demo % jdb -attach localhost:5005                                                                                             

java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.implRead(NioSocketImpl.java:318)
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.read(NioSocketImpl.java:346)
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl$1.read(NioSocketImpl.java:796)
        at java.base/java.net.Socket$SocketInputStream.read(Socket.java:1099)
        at jdk.jdi/com.sun.tools.jdi.SocketTransportService.handshake(SocketTransportService.java:133)
        at jdk.jdi/com.sun.tools.jdi.SocketTransportService.attach(SocketTransportService.java:273)
        at jdk.jdi/com.sun.tools.jdi.GenericAttachingConnector.attach(GenericAttachingConnector.java:119)
        at jdk.jdi/com.sun.tools.jdi.SocketAttachingConnector.attach(SocketAttachingConnector.java:83)
        at jdk.jdi/com.sun.tools.example.debug.tty.VMConnection.attachTarget(VMConnection.java:563)
        at jdk.jdi/com.sun.tools.example.debug.tty.VMConnection.open(VMConnection.java:369)
        at jdk.jdi/com.sun.tools.example.debug.tty.Env.init(Env.java:63)
        at jdk.jdi/com.sun.tools.example.debug.tty.TTY.main(TTY.java:1176)

Fatal error:
Unable to attach to target VM.
```

I believe I am correctly mapping port 5005 to the same port on localhost, and the application logs that it is waiting for the debugger to connect, so I'm not sure what the issue is.

My Dockerfile:

```
FROM gradle:8.1.1-jdk17 AS base
COPY --chown=gradle:gradle . /home/gradle/src
WORKDIR /home/gradle/src

FROM base AS development
EXPOSE 5005
CMD ["./gradlew", "bootRun", "--debug-jvm"]

FROM base AS build
RUN gradle build --no-daemon

FROM eclipse-temurin:17-jre-jammy AS production
EXPOSE 8080
RUN mkdir /app
COPY --from=build /home/gradle/src/build/libs/*.jar /app/
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar","/app/demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar"]
```

My compose file:

```
version: '3.8'
services:
  demo:
    build:
      context: .
      target: development
    ports:
      - "5005:5005"
      - "8080:8080"
    environment:
      - SERVER_PORT=8080
    volumes:
      - ./:/app
```

My docker logs:

```
2024-01-06 17:56:51 demo-1  | Starting a Gradle Daemon, 4 busy and 1 stopped Daemons could not be reused, use --status for details
2024-01-06 17:56:54 demo-1  | > Task :checkKotlinGradlePluginConfigurationErrors
2024-01-06 17:56:56 demo-1  | > Task :processResources
2024-01-06 17:56:59 demo-1  | > Task :compileKotlin
2024-01-06 17:56:59 demo-1  | > Task :compileJava NO-SOURCE
2024-01-06 17:56:59 demo-1  | > Task :classes
2024-01-06 17:56:59 demo-1  | > Task :resolveMainClassName
2024-01-06 17:57:01 demo-1  | 
2024-01-06 17:57:01 demo-1  | > Task :bootRun
2024-01-06 17:57:01 demo-1  | Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 5005
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorted this by removing the --debug-jvm parameter in my Dockerfile, and adding the following into build.gradle:

```
bootRun {
    jvmArgs '-Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=*:5005'
}
```